# Linux diff command not showing right comparison

Tags: diff

I really need your help to advice how to show the correct comparison test using diff command. I have two files

FileA:

```
2            1
3            4166
4            1186
5            14318
6            2451
7            64
10           3
11           18
20           5
```

FileB:

```
3            3990
4            1144
5            14368
6            2439
7            64
10           3
11           18
20           5
```

And running the diff command this way to show a side by side comparison, the output is not what I'm expecting:

```
diff -y -W 60 FileA FileB
```

The output is:

```
2            1               |  3            3992
3            4166            |  4            1144
4            1186            |  5            14372
5            14318           |  6            2439
6            2451            <
7            64                 7            64
10           3                  10           3
11           18                 11           18
20           5                  20           5
```

The expected output should be:

```
2            1               <
3            4166            |  3            3992
4            1186            |  4            1144
5            14318           |  5            14372
6            2451            |  6            2439
7            64                 7            64
10           3                  10           3
11           18                 11           18
20           5                  20           5
```

I mean, first line in FileB is missing, but diff is not capturing that. Can you please help me to fix this?

Comment: I think we can see it both ways, as you see it, and as `diff` sees it.

Comment: diff does not compare field by field. The first four lines are all entirely different, and it shows them as complete replacements. The first place it gets an actual match to synchronise is '7 64', at which point it shows one line as an insertion to get in sync. The remaining lines all match. If you want to match on only one column, you probably need awk.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to compare this

```
foo
bar
```

to this

```
baz
```

by comparing lines. You can say that

1. `foo` is only in the first file, `bar` and `baz` are the line that differs;
2. or `foo` and `baz` are the line that differs, `bar` is only in the first file;
3. or `foo` and `bar` are only in the first file, `baz` is only in the second.

Each description is true. The first two are somewhat better because in the format `diff -y` uses they take two lines each, while the third one takes three lines.

In this case `diff -y` does a good job generating two lines, not three. But still there are two possible descriptions to choose from.

You may favor the first description (where `bar` was replaced by `baz`) because this change alters just one letter; but `diff` has no concept of similar lines. Two lines are either different or not.

In your case, to compare 5 lines with 4 different lines, I can assume *any* of the 5 lines is unique to the first file and the remaining 4 lines correspond accordingly. You say the 1st line was removed; `diff` says the 5th one was removed. Both approaches are valid.

This is because `diff` works with lines and it has no concept of lines that differ only partially.

I tried `wdiff`, it works with words. This tool is able to identify `3`, `4`, `5` and `6` as identical in both your files. But it's a different tool with different output.

Comment: You may find wdiff is not in your standard distro, and needs to be installed.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I'm not able to install wdiff. But I'm trying with a bash script to compare both files taking as base the 1st column which we can say it's the key and 2nd is the value to compare.